# Seachview directing to another intent which runs php

Tags: android, android-intent, searchview

i am kind off new to android development so i just want to know whether it's possible to grab the text user enters in the search box and redirect to another activity with the text getting send to next activity via put extras?

Comment: Did you even try and search about this before asking this question?

Comment: actually i did..but my app simply crashed..and was unable to find it on google too...thought u guys might give direction.. :)

Comment: Show us what you tried and share the logcat too.